# OpenSSL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, openssl

I need to figure out how to get two OpenSSL functions for iPhone. I'm trying to keep it so I don't need another dylib, because I don't want Apple to reject my application for something so silly.

Anyways, I have an app that access an API, not one of my APIs, so I can't really change it, and also, I don't want anyone to know my public key, or use this specific 'private' api, so I can't just make a PHP script server side, which, would be easier, except that it just won't work out.

I need to be able to use something that will seal a request in OpenSSL, and also encode a public key in OpenSSL. I have the headers, and I can't seem to figure anything out.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the easiest approach to encryption and decryption on the iPhone is the Security.framework, instead of using OpenSSL directly.

See here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9

The example at the bottom (listings 2-8, 2-9 and 2-10) show RSA-1024 key pair creation plus encryption and decryption.

By using a different key, you can control the encryption/decryption method to match the requirements of your server.

Comment: *"Generally, the easiest approach to encryption and decryption on the iPhone is the Security.framework, instead of using OpenSSL directly..."* - its also the easiest way to ensure your app is vulnerable to known bugs. Apple regularly abandons its software. I have more unpatched iDevices than patched ones. If I depend on Apple and its frameworks, then I'm vulnerable. If I depend on its OpenSSL, then I rebuild the latest version and I am is up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

You can also compile OpenSSL as a library for iOS. Here is an tutorial from me:
http://www.x2on.de/2010/07/13/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-1-0-0a-library/

Comment: Thanks but couldn't get it to work, it says 'Building for simulator', 'Please standby' and terminates without any other log

Answer (score 4):

For me I found that implementing the OpenSSL pod from cocoapods was the easiest. No tutorial needed. 
Info: http://cocoapods.org/?q=openssl

```
-> OpenSSL (1.0.1)
   OpenSSL is an SSL/TLS and Crypto toolkit. Deprecated in Mac OS and gone in iOS, this spec gives your project non-deprecated OpenSSL support.
   pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0.1'
   - Homepage: http://www.openssl.org/
   - Source:   https://github.com/endSly/OpenSSL-pod.git
   - Versions: 1.0.1, 1.0.0 [master repo]
```

Comment: I found this by pod search too. Is it better than pre-compiled openssl library ?