# XCode can't find headers in /usr/include for openSSH

Tags: iphone

I know its Repost but i still dont have proper ans to this question

i am including this

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
```

but it says

```
"Openssl/x509.h: No such file or directory"
```

i did my best , added OpenSSl folder ( both way blue color folder and yellow as well)

this is my "HEader Search Path" -> **${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2  and /usr/include**

my User Header search path is  empty

#####UPDATES

how to fix this issue
in **library search path**

1)"$(SRCROOT)/" -> is fine and takes current project path

2)**$inherited -> this is taking some stupid path which i dont know , how to fix this path

**
**i want to include my openSSL path here so what should i do**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason Coco said, that header file is missing because the iPhone SDK simply does not include openSSL.

You might however, be able to build openSSL as a library and link it with your application; see [OpenSSL on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736036/openssl-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK does not include openSSL. It's only available on Mac OS X at this time. Even if you get Xcode to read the headers from Mac OS X, you won't be able to link (the libraries are simply no present on the device).