# openssl/bio.h file not found when build the application in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and i am trying to build my application, but i am getting openssl/bio.h file not found exception. I added libcrypto.a file into the Xcode directory and also set the header search paths for project. Still i am getting same issue.Can anyone help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736036/openssl-on-iphone

Comment: You set the header search path to *what* directory?  What openssl are you trying to use?

Comment: @trojanfoe- I am using the latest version of openssl-(1.0.1f). I added libcrypto.a file into the Xcode directory and set the header search path like pointing to the folder which has the libcrypto.a file.